# what is the difference between worker process,application pool and application domain?

Tags: c#, vb.net, iis

can anyone please explain what is the difference between worker process,application pool and application domain?
or application domain and application pool are same?

Comment: What don't you understand about the differences? You have been reading up on these before asking here, right?

Comment: i googled these concepts and none of it define a better picture about the difference

according to me 
application domain is for isolating applications from other applications.
Application pools also used for Isolation of Different Web Application. Hope you understand why i posted a question here.

Comment: Do you understand that application pools are IIS specific, and Application domains are not?

Comment: sorry i was not aware of that.so application domain have no role in communicating with IIS? then how its isolating one from other applications?

Comment: Did you read about the different concepts on MSDN? [Application Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx), [Application Pools](http://blogs.iis.net/tomwoolums/archive/2008/12/17/iis-7-0-application-pools.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An application pool seperates web applications on a server so it behaves completely independent of the other web applications so if another web application fails, this one wont because its seperate. The worker process basically processes all the requests for a web application. I think usually one application pool uses one worker process by default but it can use more. In process explorer it will show as W3wp.exe.  As for the difference between application domain and application pool, I'm not 100% sure but it's already been answered on this forum here:

[Difference between an application domain and an application pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486335/difference-between-an-application-domain-and-an-application-pool)