# Are there separate Worker Processes for the Sites running in same App Pool?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have four applications (A, B, C and D) running under an application pool `Pool1`.

1. Will all applications in that pool run under separate worker processes?
2. Will all the applications run separate instances of `w3wp.exe`?
3. Will all of them have their separate `APPDomain`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that each application pool will run it's own worker process so websites A, B, C & D in the same app pool will share a worker process. Within the single worker process each website will run in its own AppDomain.

There is a pretty good description here: [Difference between an application domain and an application pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486335/difference-between-an-application-domain-and-an-application-pool)

Answer (score 2):

Yes exatly only one worker process run per application pool that has multiple web apps.

Process explorer tool will be useful to check the worker process.

When host the application vie IE or any other browser in the same application pool a new worker process is added beneath the svchost.exe.

Here is the link to download the tool

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)