# Scope of HttpRuntime.Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, httpruntime.cache

Is it possible to retrieve `HttpRuntime.Cache` from another application?

i am having two applications ,

for example App-A, App-B

in App-A i am inserting values to cache

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(sCacheKey, sCacheValue, Nothing, Now.AddHours(CInt(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CacheExpirationHours"))), TimeSpan.Zero)
```

I am not able to retrieve the values in App-B

```
Dim strList As String
strList = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(sCacheKey)
```

it is simply returning as Nothing. what i am doing wrong?

Comment: HttpRuntime.Cache exists in the app domain, so no you can't access it from another app. You'll need to expose that cache via wcf, http, etc if you want another app to access it.  Also consider using a distributed cache.

Comment: I think it's better to use Redis or Memcached.

Comment: Someone else asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244105/sharing-an-httpruntime-cache-across-two-iis-applications

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[HttpRuntime.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) exists in the app domain, so no you can't access it from another app. You'll need to expose that cache via wcf, web api, etc if you want another app to access it. Also consider using a distributed cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable answer.